# How to track SQL errors in CakePHP on production site

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

i want to track the errors on production site if the insert or update function didnot work .

to test this fucntionality i have cretaed a function in my controller :-

```
function testSqlStatement(){

  $this->autoRender = false;
  $save=array('UserId'=>'48','Active'=>'qw');
  $this->User->saveAll($save);
  $log = $this->getDataSource()->error;
  $this->log('sql error' . print_r($log, true), 'sql');
  }
```

the error i get is :-   Call to undefined method AdminsController::getDataSource() 
where i have to define the getdatasource? is there any other method to know the error without chaning the debug to 2

Answer (score 0):

You use following way :

The onError callback gets called by DboSource class in create(), read(), update() and delete() methods. So, if you are writing a custom query and calling it through model’s query() method then onError() won’t get called automatically, but don’t worry, you can still track the SQL error(s). These CRUD methods, alongwith query(), in turn use execute() method which sets SQL error to a class variable, named ‘error’

The lastError() methods have been already implemented in each DBO source (mysql, mssql etc.).

Lets move forward to write our model callback. An example code to log the error in a text file would be would be something like:

```
<?php

function onError()
{
    // The SQL error
    $error = $this->getDataSource()->error;

    // Log file
    $logFile = LOGS . 'sql_errors.txt';

    // Log the error
    file_put_contents($logFile, file_get_contents($logFile) . $error . "\n\n");
}
```

This code can go in your app_model.

Another example code to mail the error would be something like

```
function onError()
{
    // The SQL error
    $error = $this->getDataSource()->error;

    // Send the error
    mail('webmaster@example.com', 'SQL errors', $error);
}
```

Comment: i have used above code :- 
but it give notice :- Notice (8): Undefined property: Mysql::$error [APP/Model/AppModel.php, line 40]
the line no 40 is $error = $this->getDataSource()->error;

Comment: let me check it , m chinkng

Comment: I dont know Which is `LINE 40` in your model code , specify it here

Comment: check my above comment
the lne no 40 is $error = $this->getDataSource()->error;

Comment: the code that you have mention is from http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/07/05/how-to-track-sql-errors-in-cakephp-on-production-site/#comment-140031
i have chedkced that too.

the line that works for me is   $log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);and inside this i have on the debug mode.
Configure::write('debug',2);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're calling `$this->getDataSource` when `$this` is referring to a controller and not a model. You want `$this->User->getDataSource()` instead:

```
function testSqlStatement(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $save = array('UserId'=>'48','Active'=>'qw');
    $this->User->saveAll($save);
    $log = $this->User->getDataSource()->error;
    $this->log('sql error' . print_r($log, true), 'sql');
}
```